# Track cross domain sessions with ApplicationInsights

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

I am using the Azure Application Insights JavaScript library to keep track of some business flow in my application. AppInsights uses a `session_id` (saved to a cookie) to connect separate events into a flow. This value is automatically generated and managed.

The problem is that now the business flow requires me to track events from multiple domains. Can I somehow tell AppInsights-JS that I want to continue a previous session? If the current session could be serialized into a string, and loaded on an other page, that would be perfect, I could just pass it along as a query parameter to the page on the other domain.

My first thought was to save the `ai_user` and `ai_session` cookie values, but it feels like hacking the system.

The solution I am currently using is to maintain a custom sessionid myself, and pass it to every tracked event as a custom dimension. This way I can filter the events based on this field to obtain the events of a business flow. It's a bit harder to use this way.

Is it safe to just save and store the cookie values? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Have you found out a nice solution to solve this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript SDK doesn't support this functionality today. But you can write a [TelemetryInitializer](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#addtelemetryinitializer) to override the `ai_session` and `ai_user`.

Comment: An example on how to track it cross-domain would be useful with the `telemetryInitializer`